# Received cashiers check

Tags: cashier-check

I received a cashiers check in the Mail and there is no letter nothing.  I called to authenticate with the bank of was written from and customer service told me to take it to my bank.  How can I authenticate it before taking it to my bank?

Comment: is it made out just to you or does it say "Meleelee or another persons name"

Comment: Could be a scam. By cashing you may be agreeing to something that will cost you much more.

Comment: @Mattman944 US law holds that unsolicited goods or cash mailed to you are considered gifts and you can keep them without consequence.

Comment: @CareyGregory do you have a source for that? I think it is wrong, and keeping it is considered _theft_. You even have to make a reasonable effort to conserve it, and return it when contacted about it.

Comment: @Aganju It would only be theft if you knew the check had been sent in error. If it was sent as a marketing gimmick or an enticement of some sort, it's yours to keep. Same as the charities who send nickles in their mailings. That's your nickle now and you have no obligation to return it or donate.

Comment: That said, I'm confident this is some sort of scam. Most likely cashing that check means you're signing up for something or the check is a loan. I don't think there's enough information in the question to answer it.

Comment: Follow up -- read the fine print on the "check". If it is a fraud, it may look like a cashiers check, but it will have conditions in fine print on it. Something like: *by cashing this check you agree to ...* I receive a few of these every year.

Comment: @Aganju [USPS](https://about.usps.com/publications/pub300a/pub300a_v04_revision_072019_tech_021.htm): "By law, unsolicited merchandise is yours to keep."

Comment: @Kevin This isn't a question about unsolicited merchandise.

Comment: @CareyGregory I assumed it was a fake check and that a few days later someone will contact Meleelee asking them to return the money via some non-reversable method.